# Logging from an sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I use the [s3 resolver plugin](https://github.com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/tree/f2aae1aa9918ace87499c79a3fbd806025de224e) for sbt.

I have changed the credentials provider:

```
lazy val s3CredentialsProvider = {bucket: String =>
    new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
      new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(),
      PropertyFilesCredentialProvider.create(bucket)
    )
  }
```

where the `PropertyFilesCredentialProvider` is a custom provider.

I have done the following where:

- we added a `ConsoleLogger` using `sbt.util.internal`
- we added a `System.out.println`

instead.

I've published the plugin and have been using it in another plugin. It looks like my plugin is being used because the resolver attempts to use a different access key each time but we cannot see the logs from our class.

How can we add `logging` when we have code in an `AutoPlugin`?

The code for the Provider looks like this:

import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, InputStream}
import java.util.Properties

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.{AWSCredentials, AWSCredentialsProvider, BasicSessionCredentials}
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.{AssumeRoleRequest, AssumeRoleResult, Credentials}

/** Creates a credential provider that reads a `roleArn` property from a file
  * and assumes the role using STS.
  *
  * This is based on https://github.com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/blob/master/src/main/scala/fm/sbt/S3URLHandler.scala#L84
  *
  * @param file Properties file holding the ROLE_ARN for the project.
  */
class PropertyFilesCredentialProvider(file: File)
  extends AWSCredentialsProvider {

  private val ROLE_ARN_KEY: String = "roleArn"
  private val AWS_REGION: String = "<AWS_REGION>"

  protected def getRoleArn: String = {
    val is: InputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
    try {
      val props: Properties = new Properties()
      props.load(is)
      props.getProperty(ROLE_ARN_KEY)
    } finally is.close()
  }

  def createAWSCredentials(credentials: Credentials): AWSCredentials = {
    System.out.println("Retrieved AWS Session Token and Credentials for assuming role")
    new BasicSessionCredentials(credentials.getAccessKeyId,
      credentials.getSecretAccessKey,
      credentials.getSessionToken)
  }

  def assumeRole(roleArn: String): AssumeRoleResult = {
    System.out.println(s"Making a request to AWS STS with the roleArn: $roleArn to assume a role")
    val stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder
      .standard
      .withRegion(AWS_REGION)
      .build

    val assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest
    assumeRoleRequest.setRoleArn(roleArn)
    stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest)
  }

  override def getCredentials: AWSCredentials = {
    val roleArn = getRoleArn
    if (roleArn == null || roleArn == "") {
      System.out.println(s"Key of name $ROLE_ARN_KEY was not found in file at ${file.getAbsolutePath}")
      return null
    }
    System.out.println(s"$ROLE_ARN_KEY was read from ${file.getAbsolutePath} successfully")
    val assumeRoleResult = assumeRole(roleArn)
    System.out.println("Request to assume role using AWS STS successful")
    createAWSCredentials(assumeRoleResult.getCredentials)
  }

  override def refresh(): Unit = {}
}

object PropertyFilesCredentialProvider {

  private val DOT_SBT_DIR: File =
    new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".sbt")

  /** Uses a bucket specific propertyfile to read AWS `roleArn` from and provides it
    * to the PropertyFilesCredentialProvider.
    *
    * @param bucket Name of the S3 bucket.
    * @return a PropertyFileCredentialProvider
    */
  def create(bucket: String): PropertyFilesCredentialProvider = {
    val fileName = s".${bucket}_s3credentials"
    System.out.println("Using the Property Files Credential Provider")
    System.out.println(s"Reading $fileName for AWS Credentials ")
    val file: File = new File(DOT_SBT_DIR, fileName)
    new PropertyFilesCredentialProvider(file)
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Attempts to use `streams.value.log` failed with the error:

```
`value` can only be called on a task within a task definition macro, 
 such as :=, +=, ++=, or Def.task.
[error]   val logger = streams.value.log
[error]
```

Attempts to use `ConsoleLogger` which is a sub class of `Logger` but instantiated within the class. The apply method on it was invoked like this:

```
val logger = sbt.internal.util.ConsoleLogger(System.out)
logger.info("s"Key of name $ROLE_ARN_KEY was not found in file at ${file.getAbsolutePath}"")
```

inside the class above. That did not output the logs either.

> I created two loggers, one for the class and another for the companion object as members and not within the class extending `AutoPlugin`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Excellent suggestion but unfortunately, it did not help me in this case. I have updated the question with the error.

Comment: I tried using `ConsoleLogger` which is a subclass of `Logger` before switching to `println`. However we generated the `Logger` inside the `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of adding logging to classes that you defined for your `AutoPlugin`

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object TestPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  class SomeClassThatNeedsLogger(logger: Logger) {
    def doSomeLogging(): Unit = {
      logger.info("It logs")
    }
  }

  object autoImport {
    val someClassThatNeedsLoggerHolder = taskKey[SomeClassThatNeedsLogger]("Holds instance of SomeClassThatNeedsLogger")
    val runSomeClassThatNeedsLogger = taskKey[Unit]("Runs SomeClassThatNeedsLogger")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
    Seq(
      someClassThatNeedsLoggerHolder := new SomeClassThatNeedsLogger(streams.value.log),
      runSomeClassThatNeedsLogger := someClassThatNeedsLoggerHolder.value.doSomeLogging()
    )
  }
}
```

And running gives us a log entry:

```
> runSomeClassThatNeedsLogger
[info] It logs
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 6, 2019 9:47:15 AM
```

Some notes on errors you're getting

> `value` can only be called on a task within a task definition macro,
>   such as :=, +=, ++=, or Def.task.

This tells you that `streams.value` can be used only in task definitions like `someClassThatNeedsLoggerHolder := new SomeClassThatNeedsLogger(streams.value.log)`

> ConsoleLogger using sbt.util.internal

As the package name suggests, this is an internal package and subject to a change in next versions of sbt. It should not be used in your plugin definitions.