# Setting cannot depend on a task when adding logging to setting key

Tags: scala, sbt

I am updating an `sbt plugin` which has a `SettingKey` from the [`fm-sbt-s3-resolver`](https://github.com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver). I have made some progress on explicitly adding the needed setting as a side effect of the question here:

[Logging from an sbt plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545388/logging-from-an-sbt-plugin)

```
object MyPlugin {
  override def requires = S3ResolverPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements

override lazy val globalSettings = Seq(
    resolvers ++= repos,
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    S3ResolverPlugin.autoImport.s3CredentialsProvider := {bucket: String =>
      new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
        new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(),
        PropertyFilesCredentialProvider.create(bucket, streams.value.log)
      )
    }
  )
}
```

When I try to add `logging` using `streams.value.log`, sbt throws an error:

```
[error]  A setting cannot depend on a task
[error] PropertyFilesCredentialProvider.create(bucket, streams.value.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to depend on setting `sLog` instead of task `streams`.

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object Logs extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val settingLog = settingKey[Unit]("Uses setting sLog")
    val taskLog = taskKey[Unit]("Uses task streams log")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    settingLog := { sLog.value.info("Logging on settings execution") },
    taskLog := { streams.value.log.info("Logging on task execution") }
  )
}
```

The difference with `settingLog` is the it will log when sbt boots.

```
~/w/t/stackoverflow $ sbt
[info] Logging on settings execution
```

Repeated calls to `settingLog` will not produce any logging anymore. But `taskLog` will print a log every time you call it